# Is there an alternative for <flux:field.file /> in Flux/Fluid TYPO3

Tags: typo3, flux, fluid

`<flux:field.file />` is deprecated in the latest version of TYPO3/Fluid.

Is there an alternative? How can I upload my videos in the backend right now?

Comment: this is for frontend. I need a backend input for my content element template

Comment: Actually deprecation note is `DEPRECATED - use flux:field instead`, so I assume they moved the functionality there. FYI: just guessing, as I don't use flux.

Comment: Try this : <flux:field.file name="file" label="File upload" allowed="jpg,png,svg" showThumbnails="1" useFalRelation="1" required="1" />
> Not sure , it works or not !!!

Comment: See https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1856#issuecomment-748726485

Answer (score 0):

You can try that:

*Configuration:*

```
<flux:field.inline.fal name="settings.bgImage" label="LLL:EXT(...)" required="0" />
```

*Preview:*

```
<v:content.resources.fal field="settings.bgImage" as="images" record="{record}">
<f:for each="{images}" as="image">
    <f:if condition="{image}">
        <f:image src="{image.id}" treatIdAsReference="1" maxWidth="100" />
    </f:if>
</f:for></v:content.resources.fal>
```

*Main:*

```
<f:if condition='{settings.bgImage}'>
{v:content.resources.fal(field: 'settings.bgImage') -> v:iterator.first() -> v:variable.set(name: 'bgImage')}
<f:image treatIdAsReference="true" src="{bgImage.id}" title="{bgImage.title}" alt="{bgImage.alternative}" width="100c" /></f:if>
```